# Concatenate list items with other column values

Tags: python, pandas

I came across a requirement where i need to concatenate list of items in column with other column values like below.

input:

```
     ColumnA ColumnB
0  [x, y, z]  Failed
1     [x, y]  Passed
```

output:

```
     ColumnA ColumnB                         ColumnC
0  [x, y, z]  Failed  [x:Failed, y:Failed, z:Failed]
1     [x, y]  Passed            [x:Passed, y:Passed]
```

Can some please let me know how can i achieve this using python and pandas.

Answer (score 1):

Use nested list comprehension with `f-string`s in performance is important:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ColumnA": [list('xyz'), list('xy')],
                   "ColumnB": ['Failed', 'Passed']})
    
df['ColumnC'] = [[f'{z}:{y}' for z in x] for x, y in df[['ColumnA', 'ColumnB']].to_numpy()]
print (df)
     ColumnA ColumnB                         ColumnC
0  [x, y, z]  Failed  [x:Failed, y:Failed, z:Failed]
1     [x, y]  Passed            [x:Passed, y:Passed]
```

Another idea, slowier is use `apply`:

```
df['ColumnC'] = df.apply(lambda x: [f'{z}:{x["ColumnB"]}' for z in x['ColumnA']], axis=1)
```

Slowiest is use `explode` with `groupby`.

---

```
#test for 20k rows
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)
    

In [29]: %timeit (df.explode('ColumnA').assign(ColumnC=lambda d: d['ColumnA']+':'+d['ColumnB']).groupby(level=0)['ColumnC'].apply(list))
600 ms ± 10 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)


In [34]: %timeit df.apply(lambda r: list(map(':'.join, product(r['ColumnA'], [r['ColumnB']]))), axis=1)
268 ms ± 3.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

---

```
In [30]: %timeit [[f'{z}:{y}' for z in x] for x, y in df[['ColumnA', 'ColumnB']].to_numpy()]
36.4 ms ± 894 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [31]: %timeit df.apply(lambda x: [f'{z}:{x["ColumnB"]}' for z in x['ColumnA']], axis=1)
363 ms ± 2.08 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 1):

To use pandas only, you can `explode`, concatenate, and transform to list:

```
df['ColumnC'] = (df.explode('ColumnA')
                   .assign(ColumnC=lambda d: d['ColumnA']+':'+d['ColumnB'])
                   .groupby(level=0)['ColumnC'].apply(list)
                )
```

A faster solution would be to use `itertools.product`:

```
from itertools import product
df['ColumnC'] = df.apply(lambda r: list(map(':'.join, product(r['ColumnA'], [r['ColumnB']]))), axis=1)
```

output:

```
     ColumnA ColumnB                         ColumnC
0  [x, y, z]  Failed  [x:Failed, y:Failed, z:Failed]
1     [x, y]  Passed            [x:Passed, y:Passed]
```